# How to stop yii default error pages

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii framework, in this i am working on small project but it throwing error pages 
if any errors appearing from database..

Please help me how to stop these error pages and  to display some customized error page

I have been struggling to get this for some time, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to comment the line in index.php

`defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);`

Comment: Well Done @Abhi. Easy Way To Hide Those Notices/Warnings.

Answer (score 6):

To customize error page modify the view: `/protected/views/site/error` - "site" is your default controller.

You can change it via `/protected/config/main.php`:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
    'errorAction'=>'myController/error',
),
```

And in your controller you have the action:

```
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {           
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        echo $error['message'];
    }
    else
        $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}
```

So you can do whatever you want.